# `white-space: nowrap` weirdness

Tags: css

I ran across a curious situation while using `white-space: nowrap` on two `span` elements.

Instead of preventing a line-break within the `span`, it also prevents linebreaks between the `span` elements.

If I place the `span` elements next to eachother on the same line of my code the second `span` cannot drop to the next line.

If I place the same `span` elements on different lines (or use a space inbetween) the second span will drop down.

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) the whitespace should only handle the space inside an element.

**How can I get the behaviour where the second span will drop down if the total width of both `span` elements is wider than the container `div`? (With CSS only and while keeping the text within a span on the same line)**

```css
span{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div{
  width: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello there.</span><span> I don t wrap at all!</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Hello there.</span>
  <span>I do wrap!!!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no white space between your spans, so where should the wrap occur?

Comment: If what you want to do is to always break spans in a certain context, then give the parent a common class and select the child spans and set display to `inline-block`, e.g., `.my-parent-class > span { display: inline-block; }`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @denmch Between the spans. It should basically add a `<br/>` inbetween them if the `span` elements don't fit on a line. But with css only.

Comment: @denmch Actually that s exactly what I want. And it's so simple that I am having a facepalm moment xD.

Comment: Don't feel bad, @RMo. I just told a co-worker yesterday that I felt like a complete fraud for not knowing something, and he reassured me that if you don't feel that way once a week, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since denmch did not post a formal answer I will post it myself. And what I think was going on.

Because the spans were next to eachother without a linebreak or space inbetween the browser interprets the two span elements with `white-space: nowrap;` as a single word. Basically something like this:

```css
span{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><span>He</span>llo</p>
```

Not wrapping this word makes sense in this scenario. So this is how an inline element behaves. We can simply change the `display` to `display: inline-block`. Now the element loses the behavior it had while it was an `inline` element.

Therefore we can add `display: inline-block`. And now it will treat the text inside the span as a single word and the relevant span will drop down if the content of the two `span` elements does not fit in the div's width:

```css
span{
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span.inline-block{
  display: inline-block;
}
div{
  width: 8em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
div>span:first-child{
  background: yellow;
}
div>span:nth-child(2){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello there.</span><span>I don t wrap at all!</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='inline-block'>Hello there.</span>
  <span class='inline-block'>I do wrap!!!</span>
</div>
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is your problem.

It's actually not a bug.
What is happening is, the default display CSS property of the `<span>` parent div is inline

When you add a break in the code it is interpreted by the browser as a new line, so the `<span>` element is placed on a new line.  By simply giving the span element in the first div a property of display:block fixes the problem.

```css
span{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div{
  width: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello there.</span><span style='display:block;'> I don t wrap at all!</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Hello there.</span>
  <span>I don t wrap at all!</span>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

denmch does make a point though, in my answer I just debugged your post instead or thinking about what you were saying.  You are not understanding what white-space:nowrap; does. Your question relates to the positioning of elements not wrapping at all.

**EDIT:**

This is just to clarify for the OP:

Your question relates to a default handling of HTML and CSS properties in browsers.  So a purely CSS solution would not be possible with his HTML.

Refer to: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Actually `display:block` will not work. Because that will also place the text on a new line if it fits next to the other span. Change it to inline-block and please answer without modifying the html, since I was explicitely looking for a css solution.

Comment: You are coming off as very hostile, what the ^&%& is your problem?

Comment: Uhm it's not hostile at all. I just want a good answer that others can use for future reference. denmch gave it already in the comments. But i don't  think he'll post a formal answer.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the OP's question was, but I know your answer solves exactly my problem... so it was actually useful for future reference.